# Django query performance when using filters on all

Tags: django, django-queryset

what are the performance implications between the following two options to get the data:

```
def get_something(self):
    something = [s for s in self.something.all() if s.type in(
        TYPE2, TYPE1)]
    return sorted(something, key=lambda e: e.get_timestamp())
```

vs

```
def get_something(self):
    something = self.something.all().filter(
    type__in=[TYPE1, TYPE2])
    return sorted(something, key=lambda e: e.get_timestamp())
```

It seems the second one would require less memory but I was told that the second one would result in two queries instead of 1. Is this the case and what is considered better style

Answer (score 3):

Both snippets will lead to single db hit.  In simple case the second snippet will be faster.

But the key question is: how do you get the `self`?

If it is a single object loaded with `get()` method then the second option is the way to go.

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=123) # or MyModel.objects.filter(...).first()
print obj.get_something()
```

But if you load the several objects with `prefetch_related()` then the first option may be more efficient:

```
for obj in MyModel.objects.prefetch_related('something').filter(...):
    print obj.get_something()
```